# Named optional argument and multiple argument order

Tags: python, closures

I have a function wrapper like this.

```
def funcWrapper(fn_ng, order=None, *args ):
    def clsr(X):
        if order is not None:
            X = calc_poli_dsX(X, order)
        return fn_ng(X, *args);
    return clsr;
```

However, if I use this function as below:

```
mGrdnt = funcWrapper( gd.squared_error, dsX1, dy, order=None)
mGrdnt = funcWrapper( gd.squared_error, dsX1, dy)
```

I have error of

> TypeError: funcWrapper() got multiple values for keyword argument
> 'order'

My guess was that, if I do not specify 'order', funcWrapper will pass 'dsX1' and 'dy' are passed as *arg, but it turned out they are not. No matter I specify an optional argument, it seems that 'dsX1' and 'dy' all go into the 'order' named optional argument.

How can I make a function wrapper that can pass dsX1 and dy into *arg when the optional argument is/or is not specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify the call:

```
arr = [dsX1, dy]
funcWrapper(gd.squared_error, None, *arr)
```

or you can do something like this:

```
funcWrapper(gd.squared_error, [dsX1, dy])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that I always have to follow the order. If I do like funcWrapper(gd.squared_error, [dsX1, dy]), [dsX1, dy] goes into optional and it does not work. If I do funcWrapper(gd.squared_error, *arr), dsX1 goes into option...